# str_extract: match words near each other

Tags: r, regex, stringr, lookbehind

I would like to extract a string matching `dog|cat` (0-5 words, \r, \n or spaces between) `1.` and some more text until `2.`appears.

```
myStrings <- c(
"the dog says: 1. hello cat 2. I do not care",
"the dog barks ba ba ba ba ba ba ba and says: 1. no 2. no",
"the doggie says: 1. hello 2. you",
"the cat is angry and asks: 1. hello dog 2. go away",
"the dog says: 2. nothing 3. nothing")
```

My approach is:

```
str_extract(string=myStrings,pattern=regex("(dog|cat(?:\\w+\\W+){1,5}?1.).*(?=2.)"))
```

I tried to implement this (https://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html) , however, my regex matches

```
> [1] "dog says: 1. hello cat " "dog barks ba ba ba ba ba
> ba ba: 1. no " "doggie says: 1. hello " "dog " "dog says: "
```

What I would need is

```
 > [1] "dog says: 1. hello cat " "NA" "NA" "the cat is angry and asks: 1. hello dog " "NA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lookbehind assertion is unbounded, meaning, it can match any amount of tokens. The engine needs to statically be able to determine the length of the lookbehind.

Btw, it seems you have uneven parenthesis in your regex, which means I don't know which tokens are supposed to be included in the lookbehind. If you include anything like `\w+`, it will be unbounded.

Comment: thank you for your input. I think I did not state my question very clearly and, therefore, edited it.